# Node.js parse json

Tags: json, node.js

i am trying to convert the string to JSON. This is my string

```
{_id : demo,version : 2,members : [{_id : 0,host : 192.168.1.46:27017},{_id : 1,host : 192.168.1.93:27017}]}
```

i am trying to convert the string to json but its showing error

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token _
```

I have tried all json functions to convert this to JSON but its getting failed because of the single quotes are missing in the string...

How to fix this ?

Comment: The major problem there is no quotes in that string..

Answer (score 1):

The keys in your JSON document should be in quotes: `{"_id": "value"}`

Comment: Ya i know its missing... is there way to invoke this ?

Comment: @balaphp Are you creating this string yourself? Better work pattern is to create string from object with`JSON.stringify(object)` and recreate object from string with `JSON.parse(string)`

Comment: Well, that API is not JSON.  If you can create a Javascript object with the API, do that first.  Then call JSON.stringify.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify your string a bit and add "" around the string values, you can use the function `eval()` to get it parsed.

```
a='{_id : "demo",version : 2,members : [{_id : 0,host : "192.168.1.46:27017"},{_id : 1,host : "192.168.1.93:27017"}]}'
v=eval('('+a+')')
```

This is not really recommended - if someone gives you a js function-call instead of this string, you would execute it without knowing...